# Why did the changes of a git commit disappear after other 2 commits (where I did not change the affected file)?

Tags: php, git, commit

What I did:
I detached the head of my working branch MOODLE_27_STABLE. I then created a new branch called patterns new, checking out the detached head state with

```
checkout -b patterns_new
```

I then changed the file db/upgrade.php on 20th of october:
[Link to this commit, I call it A](https://github.com/dasistwas/moodle-mod_datalynx/commit/728d54538d6a50be2d956dd23d9c764f97f76022)

Then, 2 commits later suddenly those changes disappeared in upgrade.php. But the commits do not mention, that db/upgrade.php was even modified.

After the first commit that followed, db/upgrade.php is still unchanged
[Link to that commit, B](https://github.com/dasistwas/moodle-mod_datalynx/commit/303e50de531dd63a8aed0abdbde3b413c2e54c77)

Then after the next commit suddenly the db/upgrade.php file is overwritten with an older commit.
[Link to that commit, C][3]

You can see in commit C, that nothing was changed viewing the diff. But in browsing the repository at this point in the history shows, that the commit A was overwritten with an older commit. (Near line 793 the additions made in commit A are not there anymore)
[Link to the db/upgrade.php at that point in the history][4]

What I did to completely replace MOODLE_27_STABLE with the patterns_new branch (based on a detached head from MOODLE_27_STABLE was later that:

```
git checkout patterns_new
git merge -s ours MOODLE_27_STABLE
git checkout MOODLE_27_STABLE
git merge patterns_new
```

(based on the following tutorial [replace branch entirely by another branch][5])

I do now fear, that that might not be the only commit, that has been overwritten. Why can that happen and how can I assure, that all of the commits in pattern_new are "restored"? Should I cherry-pick them all again?

(I had to remove the links 3 to 5, because I am not allowed to post more due to a stackoverflow rule "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ended up creating commits based on `patterns_new` when you did not have the branch checked out.

Which is fine, the commits are still there OK, but they're not on that branch. Your commit B, `303e50d`, is the last commit on that unnamed branch and is the last one that has your change.

Your commit C, `4835b67`, has the original `patterns_new` commit, `dbf4c2863`,  as its parent.

Name a new branch on `303e50d` and merge it with wherever your latest changes are and everything will be OK.

Also, note that commits are never "overwritten" or changed in any way: they can't be - the hash wouldn't match! You can only ever add new commits or have commits without branches or tags garbage collected after a few weeks.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It helped me a lot and solved the problem.